# Rounding inconsistencies when changing from currency to float in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to change a column (price) which is an object data type to use in a groupby. Changing this column to float sometimes keeps the same number of decimal places as the original, sometimes rounds to one decimal place, and sometimes gets rid of all decimal places altogether. I would like to keep the float values the same as the original due to eventual reconciliation that needs to be accurate to the decimal place. I have tried changing the column type using astye, and also pd.to_numeric. Ideally, price_3 and price_4 should apples should be 93927.82.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'product': ['apples', 'pears', 'grapes', 'oranges'], 
     'price': ['$93,927.83' , '$9,868.23', '$110,838.10', '$10,093.88']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


df['price_2'] = df['price'].str.replace('$', '').str.replace(',', '').str.replace('(', '').str.replace(')', '')
df['price_3'] = df['price_2'].astype(float)
df['price_4'] = pd.to_numeric(df['price_2'])
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken/588014

Comment: Your requirement of "eventual reconciliation that needs to be accurate to the decimal place" is just the kind of situation where floats can be problematic. Two potential solutions are (1) use ints, and store the amount as cents (so $93,927.83 becomes integer 9392783) or (2) use Python's inbuilt `Decimal` class.

Comment: *price_3 and price_4 should apples should be 93927.82.*...How do you get `93927.82` from `'$93,927.83'`? Also, no repro: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2Tf6.png

Comment: Try: `pandas.set_option('display.precision', 2)` and see if that helps with the presentation

Comment: @JonSG Thank so much for the comment. Yes, I saw the results are wanted when I printed out that column!

Comment: @slothrop Thanks for the comment. Both good suggestions that I would keep in mind!

Answer (score 1):

You likely want to set the display precision:

```py
import pandas
pandas.set_option('display.precision', 2)

df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'product': ['apples', 'pears', 'grapes', 'oranges'], 
    'price': ['$93,927.83' , '$9,868.23', '$110,838.10', '$10,093.88']
})
df['price_2'] = df['price'].str.replace('$', '').str.replace(',', '').str.replace('(', '').str.replace(')', '')
df['price_3'] = df['price_2'].astype(float)
df['price_4'] = pandas.to_numeric(df['price_2'])

print(df['price_4'])
```

Giving you:

```
0     93927.83
1      9868.23
2    110838.10
3     10093.88
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `df['price_3'] = df['price_2'].astype(float)` to `df['price_3'] = df['price_2'].apply(Decimal)`.

Comment: only thing I would add is ```from decimal import Decimal```